# Unlock bootloader in Google Pixel 3

Tags: android, pixel, bootloader, unlock, fastboot

I have a Google Pixel 3 that's stuck in a boot loop. All it does when I turn it on is, it shows the Google logo repeatedly and nothing happens. I am trying to restore it to factory settings by flashing.

But in order to do that I need to have my phone's boot loader unlocked. I connected my phone with a USB cable to my Mac, went into the Fastboot Mode and I already have the Android Platform tools installed on my Mac. In the terminal on my Mac, I can see that the device I connected via USB is being recognized. But when I execute the command `./fastboot flashing unlock` to unlock the boot loader, it fails.

What should I do?

Pixel 3 Fastboot:

[image]

Commands I ran:

[image]